# Azure Functions isolated .Net 6.0 + SignalR

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, .net-6.0

My goal is to:

- In scheduled functions - add message to SignalR
- In SPA application (vue.js) subscribe to the event and call API to update the view

For now I'm trying to get anything to/from SignalR in my Function app (isolated, .net 6.0).

What I have in a function app:

```
    [Function("negotiate")]
    public HttpResponseData Negotiate(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = "AdminHub", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"SignalR Connection URL = '{connectionInfo.Url}'");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        response.WriteString($"Connection URL = '{connectionInfo.Url}'");
        
        return response;
    }
}

    [Function("SendMessage")]
    [SignalROutput(HubName = "AdminHub", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")]
    public SignalRMessage SendMessage(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.HttpRequestData req)
    {
        return
            new SignalRMessage
            {
                Target = "cancelToHandle",
                MethodName = "cancelToHandle",
                Arguments = new[] { "hello" }
            };
    }

    [Function("SignalRTest")]
    public static async Task SignalRTest([SignalRTrigger("AdminHub", "messages", "cancelToHandle", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")] string message, ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Receive {message}.");
    }
```

Negotiate function is not called. When should it be called?

If I call SendMessage, no error, but nothing happens in SignalR service. Should I see connections and messages there? (zero in the Metrics for now).

I've tried to create a test "emulator" client - just a console application:

```
var url = "http://<azureSignalRUrl>/AdminHub";

var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(url)
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

// receive a message from the hub
connection.On<string, string>("cancelToHandle", (user, message) => OnReceiveMessage(user, message));

await connection.StartAsync();

// send a message to the hub
await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", "ConsoleApp", "Message from the console app");

void OnReceiveMessage(string user, string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{user}: {message}");
}
```

and it throws the exception ": 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (:80)'

I think I'm missing overall understanding of what is supposed to happen:

- when should negotiate function be triggered
- can I see messages that I send in Azure portal (in SignalR service)?
- how can I easily receive them in testing purposes
- what do parameters/properties mean (target / method name / category). Example:
  SignalRTriggerAttribute has the following constructor
  public SignalRTriggerAttribute(string hubName, string category, string @event, params string[] parameterNames);
  and Output binding receives any custom model I create?
- which settings should be set in SignalR service - for now all I set it Serverless mode + CORS

Answer (score -2):

Here are the few link which will help in using SignalIr service extension in functions

Using SignalIr service extension
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/Extensions/SignalR/SignalRFunction.cs

Below is the sample link for triggering negotiate function
https://github.com/Log234/azure-functions-signalr-dotnet-isolated-demo/blob/main/SignalRDemo/NegotiationFunctions.cs

for complete understanding of SignalIR here is the [Github](https://github.com/Log234/azure-functions-signalr-dotnet-isolated-demo/tree/main/SignalRDemo) and [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) document.